# Orchard CMS Import not importing complete file

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I am attempting to import thousands of forum posts into my Orchard website (using the NGM.Forum module). I imported the Threads without difficulty, but when I attempt to import the Post ContentItems the Import process only imports the *last* element in the `<Data>` element. I have made test Posts and exported them via Export, but the same thing occurs.

The Posts do not have an Id. If I leave the Id blank, nothing is imported. If I add `Id="{GUID}"` the last row will be imported.

A sample:

```
<!--Exported from Orchard-->
<Orchard>
  <Recipe>
    <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
    <Author>admin</Author>
    <ExportUtc>2016-03-18T07:01:06.0979684Z</ExportUtc>
  </Recipe>
  <Data>
    <Post Id="1" Status="Published">
      <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=user.name" Container="/alias=forums\/thread" CreatedUtc="2012-03-23T02:44:34Z" PublishedUtc="2016-03-18T06:49:22.4244229Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-03-23T02:44:34Z" />
      <PostPart Text="BB" />
    </Post>
    <Post Id="2" Status="Published">
      <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=user.name" Container="/alias=forums\/thread" CreatedUtc="2012-03-23T02:44:34Z" PublishedUtc="2016-03-18T06:57:27.3540795Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-03-23T02:44:34Z" />
      <PostPart Text="AA" />
    </Post>
  </Data>
</Orchard>
```

I have seen two questions also with issue, but neither have been resolved and are quite old.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much head scratching I tried adding an `Identity` to the `Post` content type. I then added an `IdentityPart` element to the XML recipe file with the ID in the `Identifier` attribute. This fixed my issue. Not sure what was wrong, but I can now import my files.

There have been some changes to the ImportExport module in the Orchard 1.9.3 release.